# Export blender animation to .gif

Tags: animation, export

I was wondering is there any way to export animation to .gif image from blender? I have seen people posting projects on Instagram and Twitter. I thought those were video formats but I was surprised to see a lot of them are Gif images. I already know that I can't export gif image from Blender but I would like to know is there any plugin which can help me to achieve a similar result?

Here is an example: https://twitter.com/i/status/1410900887921434625

Comment: i cannot speak for others...but i use extra applications for that and often just online converter...

Comment: You can import jpg into ScreenToGif app then save as .gif

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know there are converters but I want something that will make my life easy,  just want to record my projects and export them to a gif image so I can post them on social networks.